# What is the meaing of abort http request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, frontend, fetch

I saw many times an useRef of AbortController to abort axios request, what is the meaning of this? Why is so important?
This is an example i found in useEffect hook:

```
      abortControllerRef.current?.abort();
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Cancelling stale requests instead of leaving them hanging around in memory will save some browser resources used for:

1. Networking
2. Parsing
3. `Promise`-handling business

It is a good practice & there's no good alternative at the moment